# Simplify nested Python code

Tags: python

I have written a small helper function which I use to check if a navigation item is active. The code works as I expected, but it looks a little bit nested. Does anyone know how to simplify it?

```
def url_name_active(view_name, name, exact=True, exclude=None):
    exclude_names = exclude.split(',') if exclude else None

    if exclude:
        for exclude_name in exclude_names:
            if exclude_name in view_name:
                return None

    if exact and name == view_name or \
            not exact and name in view_name:
        return 'active'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how long you mind your lines being, the first conditional can be reduced to the unnested

```
if exclude and any(exclude_name in view_name for exclude_name in exclude.split(',')):
    return None
```

The entire method can be boiled down to the (more or less unreadable) two-liner

```
if not (exclude and any(exclude_name in view_name for exclude_name)) and (exact and name == view_name or not exact and name in view_name):
    return 'active'
```

You mention that you ultimately want to check if something is `'active'` or not. With the above observation, the function returns `'active'` exactly if

```
not (exclude and any(exclude_name in view_name for exclude_name)) and (exact and name == view_name or not exact and name in view_name)
```

so if you only care about the truth value of that expression, you could simply

```
return not (exclude and any(exclude_name in view_name for exclude_name)) and (exact and name == view_name or not exact and name in view_name)
```

and not have any conditionals.